# Bower Components not referencing in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, bower

I have added angular and bootstrap in my rails application using bower but it does not render any javascript.

**CSS and JAVA SCIPT both are not working**

Following the the code.

**vendor\assets\javascript\application.js**

```
//= require angular/angular
//= require_tree .
var receta = angular.module('receta',[
]);
receta.controller('mainc',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.status = "AAA";
}]);
```

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)    
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Receta
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","bower_components")

    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","bower_components","bootstrap","assets","fonts")
    config.assets.precompile << %r(.*.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$)

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

**app\views\home\index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="receta">
  <div ng-controller="mainc" class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h1 ng-if="name">Hello, {{status}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" autofocus ng-model="status">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**application.html.erb** - layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Receta</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: might be it conflict with `vendor/assets/javascript/application.js` with `app/assets/javascript/application.js` due to same file names

Comment: @GaganGami thanks. please post it as answer so i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including two different files with same name. **`vendor/assets/javascript/application.js`** and **`app/assets/javascript/application.js`** which makes some conflicts and due to this reason you may face issue.